# Two Vector Features on the same place: transparency problems - openlayers

Tags: openlayers, gwt-openlayers

My goal is to have an icon on the map and be able to change it's background programmatically.

I have:
- A vector layer with externalImages as markers (images are partly-transparent)
- A vector layer with colored squares of the same size as "markers" have. Squares are true-vector.

Every marker icon have a colored-square background with the same longitude and latitude.

The problem is: colored squares are not visible under the transparent parts of marker icon.

I noticed that this problem appears only if coordinates are absolutely equals. If not - the goal is achieved, but icon and background are not match.

My icon: 
[image: My icon:]

What I have: 
[image: What I have:]

What I want to achieve: 
[image: What I want to achieve:]

I'm using gwt-openlayers.
Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!